# Локальный сервер IRSYS не работает. Почему?

Tags: сервер

Скачал локальный сервак IRSYS. Установка простая, настроек не требует. Все пакеты установились и находятся в соответствующих папках. Но когда запускаешь сайт - он не работает. Ставишь этот же сайт на хост - работает. Не работать же все время с хостом. Помогите найти ошибку. Ссылка на [IRSYS](http://irbis-team.com/15/1/9).

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, что вы сделали. По шагам. В данный момент не понятно, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Установил сервер. Как написано в инструкции создал домен и папку www, где разместил сайт с файлом index.php. В окне браузера набираю домен - выдается ошибка типа файл не найден.
Права доступа на чтение и запись установлены в файле host, домен прописался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего не прописаны адреса в файле `hosts`.

Comment: Не совсем понял. У меня есть только файл host.exe. В инструкции написано, что надо на диске Z:\home создал каталог monsi.com, перезапустить локалку и в браузере набрать http://monsi.com
Но когда я набираю команду, браузер выдает: "К сожалению, Firefox не может найти страницу monsi.com"

Comment: windows/sistem32/drivers/etc/hosts - все адреса прописаны, доступ всем на запись и чтение открыты.